# Azure DevOps pipelines: refer to old version repository

Tags: git, hash, azure-devops, repository, pipeline

It is possible to refer to the repo from a specific hash in the stage?
For example: as a parameter I give commit's hash and thanks to this parameter I can use the repo's folder from a specific version of repository in the stage 'build'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Krzysztof Madej.

In azure devops, there is no out-of-the-box method to specify a specific version of the repo via Commit Sha.

But you can achieve it through git command.

Since you already have a commit sha， you could run the `git reset --hard` with Command Line Task. Then the source repo will be rolled back to the corresponding version.

Here is the example:

```
cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)

git reset --hard $commithash
```

Classic pipeline

[image]

Yaml pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)
      
      git reset --hard Commitsha
```

In Azure Pipeline, the default checkout step is equivalent to git clone, it will contain commit history, so you can directly use git commad to roll back the repo version without disabling(`- checkout: none`) the checkout step. This could be more convenient

Comment: Do we need to set any credentials or it will work without any additional configuration?

Comment: Hi @KrzysztofMadej Thanks for your reminder . It could work without any additional configuration.  I could directly rolled back to the target repo version.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible from two reason to do this with out of the box tools.

One resource repository doesn't allow to pass specific commit:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: string  # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
    type: enum  # see the following "Type" topic
    name: string  # repository name (format depends on `type`)
    ref: string  # ref name to use; defaults to 'refs/heads/master'
    endpoint: string  # name of the service connection to use (for types that aren't Azure Repos)
    trigger:  # CI trigger for this repository, no CI trigger if skipped (only works for Azure Repos)
      branches:
        include: [ string ] # branch names which will trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # branch names which will not
      tags:
        include: [ string ] # tag names which will trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # tag names which will not
      paths:
        include: [ string ] # file paths which must match to trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # file paths which will not trigger a build
```

and the second at the moment you can't use template syntax in resource scope. And using runtime parameters is an example of template expression.

So to do this you should set

```
- checkout: none
```

to block fetching source code and then using command line handle it on your own. In this way you should be able to do this with runtime paramaters (and pass your commit sha as parameter).

You can check it out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)